# Redirect (301) single page without mod_alias?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, mod-alias

How to create pernament redirect (301) for single page in .htaccess without mod_alias ?

f.e.

http://www.example.com/oldpage  --> http://www.elpmaxe.com/newpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My teammate has given my good answer:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} www\.example\.com$ [nc]
RewriteCond %{request_uri} ^/oldpage(/)?$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.elpmaxe.com/newpage [r=301,L,NC,NS,QSA]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use mod_rewrite and the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^oldpage/(.*)$ newpage/$1 [R=301]
```